# Замедление времени вокруг игрока

Tags: unity3d

Вот поиграл я в игру TimeShift (можете брать её как пример того, что я хочу сделать), и хочу сделать замедление времени вокруг игрока, инверсию времени и остановку времени вокруг игрока.

1. Как остановить время так, чтобы мог двигаться только игрок?
2. Как инверсировать (создать инверсию) времени так, чтобы мог двигаться только игрок?
3. Как замедлить время так, чтобы мог двигаться только игрок?

Я знаю про Time.timeScale, но он меняет время всего, а мне нужно чтобы менялось время всего, кроме игрока.

Я новичок в Unity и C#

Comment: А что происходит вокруг игрока?  Если вы двигаете объекты с определенной скорость MoveSpeed, то можно добавить переменную TimeMultiplicator и умножать на нее MoveSpeed. А если через физику, то [тут](https://www.cyberforum.ru/unity/thread2634364.html) есть похожий вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для замедления и остановки времени было бы достаточно использовать `Time.unscaledTime` и все его производные у игрока.

Инверсия времени задача ощутимо сложнее. Крайне не рекомендую для новичка. Но если очень хочется, то это будет что-то вроде глобальной статической переменной, которую вы будете использовать как кастомный `TimeScale`. При этом каждый объект в такой игре должен будет реализовывать хранение истории (здесь будет уместно сделать абстрактный класс, умеющий хранить такую информацию или соответствующий компонент). И при отрицательном значении кастомного `TimeScale` начинать её проигрывать. Базовую реализацию можно подсмотреть здесь: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqlHpPzS22U .